# How olx.com show form fields on category change and submit accordingly?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to know how to design post ad form like olx whose form fields changed on category change.

Comment: thats simple, submit will not happen on form, once submit button clicked it will call a function and in that function by category they will form data and make ajax post

Comment: I need to know how form field changes on category change ; like if I select car then field comes as speed, mileage and if I select house the field comes as area, rate, price like that.

Comment: all the fields will be created for all category, but by default all fields will be hidden, using flag they will show hide the fields

Comment: But this will lead more time to load page if I have 20 categories and I will write html form field for all category in one page and show/hide accordingly.

Comment: there are may ways to those things, you can you some framework and build every thing as fragment and load by condition, but it will not take that match to load all fields.

Comment: Can you please provide sample code for this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var subs = document.querySelectorAll(".sub");

function modeChanged() {
  removeDisp();
  var chooser = document.querySelector("#chooser").value;
  if (chooser !== "") {
    document.querySelector("." + chooser).style.display = "block";
  }
}
removeDisp();

function removeDisp() {
  for (var a = 0; a < subs.length; a++) {
    subs[a].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.sub {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
label {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: block !important;
}
label span {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <select name="chooser" id="chooser" onchange="modeChanged()">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="home">Home</option>
    <option value="shop">Shop</option>
    <option value="car">Car</option>
  </select>
  <div class="sub home">
    <label><span>Type Of Home:</span>
      <input/>
    </label>
    <label><span>Price Range:</span>
      <input/>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="sub shop">
    <label><span>Shop Size:</span>
      <input/>
    </label>
    <label><span>Shop Area:</span>
      <input/>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="sub car">
    <label><span>Car Modal:</span>
      <input/>
    </label>
    <label><span>Date of purchase:</span>
      <input/>
    </label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Check it